# MongoDB embedded secondary compound index covered slow query

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have following embedded secondary compound index:

```
db.people.ensureIndex({"sources_names.source_id":1,"sources_names.value":1})
```

Here is part of db.people.getIndexes():

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "sources_names.source_id" : 1,
        "sources_names.value" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "diglibtest.people",
    "name" : "sources_names.source_id_1_sources_names.value_1"
}
```

So I run following index covered query:

```
db.people.find({ "sources_names.source_id": ObjectId('5166d57f7a8f348676000001'), "sources_names.value": "Ulrike Weiland" }, {"sources_names.source_id":1, "sources_names.value":1, "_id":0} ).pretty()
{
    "sources_names" : [
        {
            "value" : "Ulrike Weiland",
            "source_id" : ObjectId("5166d57f7a8f348676000001")
        }
    ]
}
```

It took about 5 seconds. So I run explain:

```
db.people.find({ "sources_names.source_id": ObjectId('5166d57f7a8f348676000001'), "sources_names.value": "Ulrike Weiland" }, {"sources_names.source_id":1, "sources_names.value":1, "_id":0 }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor sources_names.source_id_1_sources_names.value_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1260353,
    "nscanned" : 1260353,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1260353,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1260353,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 4,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 4308,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "sources_names.source_id" : [
            [
                ObjectId("5166d57f7a8f348676000001"),
                ObjectId("5166d57f7a8f348676000001")
            ]
        ],
        "sources_names.value" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "dash-pc.local:27017"
}
```

But why this index-covered-query goes through whole database? How should I create index to boost performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `sources_names.value` is always a string or something?

Comment: I think this is caused by `value` being dirty in the subdocument, added an edit with some testing and conclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a multikey index (i.e. `sources_names.source_id`) in multiple places, from the docs ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries ):

> An index cannot cover a query if:
>
> any of the indexed fields in any of the documents in the collection includes an array. 
>   If an indexed field is an array, the index becomes a multi-key index index and cannot 
>   support a covered query.

You can tell this is a multikey index here form the explain:

```
"isMultiKey" : true,
```

Basically the dot notation is classed as multikey because `sources_names` is an array as such the index contains an array.

As for improving the speed: I have not looked in this but your problem is here:

```
"sources_names.value" : [
    [
        {
            "$minElement" : 1
        },
        {
            "$maxElement" : 1
        }
    ]
]
```

Whereby the index is not being optimally used to find the `sources_names.value`.

#### Edit

I thought that the answer I just gave was a bit weird, since this should not be a multikey index, so I actually went off and tested this:

```
> db.gh.ensureIndex({'d.id':1,'d.g':1})
> db.gh.find({'d.id':5, 'd.g':'d'})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("516826e5f44947064473a00a"), "d" : { "id" : 5, "g" : "d" } }
> db.gh.find({'d.id':5, 'd.g':'d'}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor d.id_1_d.g_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "d.id" : [
                        [
                                5,
                                5
                        ]
                ],
                "d.g" : [
                        [
                                "d",
                                "d"
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "ubuntu:27017"
}
```

It seems my original thoughts where right, this shouldn't be a multikey index. You have some dirty data in `value` me thinks and it is causing you problems.

I would go through your database and make sure that your records are correctly entered.

You most likely have something like:

```
{
    "sources_names" : [
        {
            "value" : ["Ulrike Weiland", 1],
            "source_id" : ObjectId("5166d57f7a8f348676000001")
        }
    ]
}
```

Some where.

Comment: I've just wrote script that checks, whether it contains correct values. But it contains only correct values - no array in sources_names.value. `Person.each do |person|
      if !person.sources_names.is_a? Array
        p person._id
        p person.sources_names.to_s
      else
        person.sources_names.each do |name|
          if !name.value.is_a? String
            p person._id
            p name.value.to_s
          end
        end
      end
    end`
I have array source_names which contain multiple dictionaries (with keys value, source_id). Maybe there is a problem?

Comment: @user2273719 max must have the right idea on the user group that hitting on the ObjectId is doing something odd